# How to tell information about parameters from reading assembly code

Tags: assembly, gdb

I'm working on a binary bomb project for my university course. In doing the different "phases" of the bomb- I have to figure out the correct input in order to prevent the bomb from detonating.

One part of the problem I am having trouble with is what do I look for within assembly code to determine information about the parameters. I would primarily like to know how many parameters the function takes in. My professor said there's an easy way and a hard way to figure this out but I am having trouble in general with identifying how much input each phase should take in. So in general, when looking at assembly code for a function- what indicators are there to make it easy to see how many parameters it takes in?

Thanks! I'm mainly using gdb for this project so if the tool helps with figuring this out let me know

Comment: there are many way to set functions parameters.Use OllyDBG. it is free and good debugger. just press ALT+C to go CPU window and in bottom right of this window you can see the stack segment(stack segment = part of memory that uses for functions parameters) and also ollyDBG analyses the parameters if it can.

Comment: Generally speaking, you look at the calling convention then check which of the places assigned to parameter passing is used in the code without being initialized.